# how to remove white space of select statement in python

Tags: python, mysql

Note:The below query is not giving any output so when I did print the query then i got to know that there is white space which is shown below in output.can any one solve this or give any solution?

```
node="some text"

sql=("select * from table where Node='%s.sam'"%node)

print("select * from table where Node='%s.sam'"%node)

cursor.execute(sql)
 data=cursor.fetchall()

 for dat in data:

     print(dat)
```

Output:

```
select * from table where Node='some text

.sam'
```

Comment: in python if you use strip() function it will remove all white spaces from string

Comment: but white space is coming in the query so how to strip() it ? %node is there for %s

Comment: `node.strip()`…!?

Comment: Ohh thank you very much you solved it @deceze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned already by other users you can use the strip() function to remove leading and trailing whitespace. If you only want to remove trailing whitespace you can use the rspace() function.

Also a small comment that does not have to do with your question but with your sample code. Generally it is bad practice to use format strings to enter parameters to your SQL query as it allows for nasty SQL injections if you allow for user input. Your driver should probably have a way of entering parameters in a safe way.

For example, with sqlite3 driver I believe you can do something similar to the following

`cursor.execute("select * from table where Node = ?", (node,))`